# When was slavery abolished in Russia?

Tags: russia, slavery

It is usually agreed that the Russian serfdom which was abolished in the mid-19th century originated in the 16th century as a form of martial law needed for armed campaigns and was especially strengthened by Peter the Great in the 17th-18th centuries.

This hints that by 16th century classical slavery (for which Russian word "раб" would be used) was already abolished or extremely rare. Yet we know that at some stage there was quite widespread slavery at least in Kievan Rus. Given this I wonder when slavery went out of use and was formally abolished in Russia?

Comment: There was gradual escalation of serfdom from the 11th/12th century onwards; with slaves eventually being converted into serfs as serfdom itself became more restrictive. Kievan Rus' recognised slavery in their legal code (Russkaya Prava) but it's unclear whether slavery was widespread. There wasn't a sudden 'blip' of liberty that disappeared but rather long downward spiral after the Black Death and Mongol horde.

Comment: Ī’m not a historian, but AFAIK the word used in Rus' for domestic forms of slavery was *холоп,* whereas *раб* ≈ Latin *servus* is a word of Church Slavonic origin with ambiguous meaning that became unambiguously refer to slavery only after introduction of Marxist historiography.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi - actually, it's backwards. "Толковый словарь Даля. — 1863—1866" shows that the word "холоп" was actually mostly used for serfs; and the word "раб" was used for serfs as a colloquialism as well without meaning outright Kievan-Rus  style slavery

Comment: Also, an important note that there were TWO classes of slaves in Kievan Rus: abovementioned *holop* only applied to "domestic" slaves; whereas *tchelyad* meant foreigners taken into slavery as prisoners. They had different rights. To FURTHER confuse things, between 12th and 17th century, *tchelyad* came to mean something completely different - household servants of a feudal lord.

Comment: @DVK What was the difference in rights between холоп и челядь?

Comment: Lol, just for fun. Can we call the Stalin era like a kind of slavery in gulags?

Comment: @Rodrigo then you would have count any country as having slavery: penal labor is employed everywhere, in the US even private companies can own prison farms.

Comment: Still going on in at least some parts of the former USSR: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/does-the-uzbekistan-government-force-children-to-perfom-slave-labor-harvesting-c

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The usual answer is that **Russia abolished slavery in 1723**. Technically speaking, there were no more slaves in Russia after this point. In reality, it meant they were merged into the class of serfs, whose lives were barely distinguishable from the formally enslaved anyway.

> State measures to increase the numbers of people liable to direct taxation in the late seventeenth and early eighteenth centuries led to the addition of two groups to the peasant estate ... All slaves, including those who lived in their owners' households, were added to the poll tax census **in 1723**. By making slaves liable to taxation, the state extended its jurisdiction to them, **thereby abolishing slavery in Russia.** There was no longer any legal distinction between slaves and seigniorial peasants, and former slaves were merged with the seigniorial peasantry.
>
> **<sub>- Moon, David. *The Russian Peasantry, 1600-1930: the World the Peasants Made.* London: Longman, 1999.</sub>**

Agricultural slaves who lived in their own houses were converted to serfs earlier, **in 1679**. Either way, as the last sentence states, this "abolition" results from the erasure of legal distinction between slavery and serfdom from the state's point of view. Practically speaking therefore, slavery essentially continued as serfdom until [Alexander II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_II_of_Russia)'s reforms [emancipated the serfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emancipation_reform_of_1861).

> Finally, as happened in the late Roman Empire, the status of peasant degraded into serfdom and become almost undistinguishable from slavery; **in 1723** the two estates were amalgamated. Confusion persisted long thereafter, **as can be seen from the fact that serfs were often sold as chattels, without land,** in spite of official efforts to restrict the practice.
>
> **<sub>- Hosking, Geoffrey A. *Russia and the Russians: a History.* Harvard University Press, 2001.</sub>**

Comment: They were added to tax census, but did the state now on formally refer to them as serfs? When slavery was declared void?

Comment: @Anixx As far as I can tell, Peter the Great abolished that status entirely at this time.

Comment: @Anixx do you actually read the answer? Slavery was never “declared void”, but merged with serfdom, to be eventually abolished by the emancipation reform of 1860s. Slaves/serfs (*крепостные*) were never freed without any compensation.

Comment: And in the USSR this continued, except now they were called "undesirables" or "political prisoners" and shipped off to massive construction projects or work camps in the Gulag.

Comment: @jwenting : not only in the Gulag: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_labor_of_Germans_in_the_Soviet_Union https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POW_labor_in_the_Soviet_Union

Comment: @Evargalo yes, POWs were also forced into slave labour in the USSR, in contravention of international treaties.

Comment: @jwenting [Penal labour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penal_labour) is distinct from slavery, though.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov this wasn't penal labour, it was slavery, pure and simple. And no, penal labour is effectively slavery. Else by your definition the concentration camp inmates in WW2 weren't slaves either, as they were incarcerated legally.

Comment: @jwenting Yes, by this definition any inmate of the camps were not slaves. Slavery implies ownership - and while Nazi ideologues intended to legalize enslavement of "subhumans", they never quite got to that point. Same with the Soviet camps - prisoners were denied some of their rights, and the terms of imprisonment definitely did not fit any definition of "humane", but they were not property of the state, of the camp administration or of any individual.

Comment: @jwenting Also note that your definition (that any forced labor is slavery, if I understand it correctly?) is not without problems too - because even today there are countries where penal labour is allowed while slavery is prohibited (Japan and USA, for example).

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov weren't Jews the property of state in Nazi Germany?

Comment: @Anixx I wouldn't say that my understanding of the wacky structure Nazis called "legal system" is comprehensive, but as far as I'm aware - Nazis did not pass any laws to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Semaphore's answer, Russian Wikipedia confirms that it was specifically Peter the Great's doing:

> Холо́пство — состояние несвободного населения в княжествах Древней Руси, в Русском государстве, отменённая Петром Первым высочайшей резолюцией на докладные пункты генерала Чернышева 19 января 1723 г
>
> ... abolished by Peter the First via the High Resolution reacting to report of General Tchernyshev on 1723/01/19

However, the process was underway for a while, with the goal being to get as many people taxable as possible, which the slaves were not. The report mentioned basically detailed how the nobility was evading prior taxation and census rules.